# php match a given number

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I got a bunch of XML files that contain an ID. e.g.

```
<WINE_PRODUCER>9456</WINE_PRODUCER>
```

I need to check, e.g. which file contains a WINE_PRODUCER id=9456:

```
$content = file_get_contents("my.xml");
$Num = 9456;
$pattern = "<WINE_PRODUCER>$Num<\/WINE_PRODUCER>";
$res = preg_match("$pattern", $content);
```

I got error PHP Warning:  `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '9'`

basically it does not like numbers in the pattern.

What do I do? googled a lot but all lead to matching a group of numbers...

PS: I do not want to use DOM xml parser in this case due to performance....

Comment: Are you on a Unix/Linux platform and can you make use of tools such as grep?

Comment: you can use strpos to accomplish the same thing. `$res = strpos("<WINE_PRODUCER>$Num<\/WINE_PRODUCER>", $content);` To test: `if ($res !== false){ // found it }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always need to match a fixed number you can just do a `strstr`.

```
$num = 9456;
$find = "<WINE_PRODUCER>". $num . "</WINE_PRODUCER>";
$found = strstr($content, $find) !== false;
```

To fix your regular expression, you need to specify delimiters:

```
$pattern = "@<WINE_PRODUCER>$Num<\/WINE_PRODUCER>@";
```

should work, but you probably don't need a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$pattern = sprintf(preg_quote('<WINE_PRODUCER>%s<\/WINE_PRODUCER>'), $num);

echo '/'.$pattern.'/';
```